# How to stop Matplotlib from inverting fits files when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, fits

I have an image but when I try to visualise it in mythic it plots upside-down.

Is there any way to stop the `imshow()` function in `matplotlib.pyplot` from displaying images upside down.

Comment: `imshow` doesn't display anything upside-down. Probably your image is upside-down from the start. You can use the `orgin` argument to set the origin where you want it.

Comment: You can try `ax.invert_yaxis()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop fits files from being imported upside down python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073379/how-to-stop-fits-files-from-being-imported-upside-down-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop fits files from being imported upside down python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073379/how-to-stop-fits-files-from-being-imported-upside-down-python)